# Spark: Load multiple files, perform same operation and merge into a single dataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, rdd

I have lots of small, individual .txt files. For each of these files, I have multiple rows divided by a space into 2 columns, start_time and end_time (a float number).

I'd like to:

- load all the .txt files
- for each row compute a new column that contains (end_time - start_time)
- for each row add a new column with the name of the file
- In the end, I want to get a single dataFrame with this schema:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
|  file_name |   start_time |   end_time |   duration |
+------------+--------------+------------+------------+
```

I know that I can simply make a loop for each file and each row and add one single line at a time to a dataframe, but I'd like to know if there is a faster way to do this.
I am not interested in the order in which things are done, but the speed of the final result. 
I see that existing functions like *textFile()* and *wholeTextFiles()* are provided in SparkContext but I could not figure out how to use them to get to do what I want.

Any direction or recommendations are greatly appreciated!

(Sorry about my poor English)

**Update:**

Thanks to @Shu for the help, this is the final code that I use to solve my problem

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, reverse, input_file_name

original_schema = [StructField("Start", FloatType(), True),
                    StructField("End", FloatType(), True)]

data_structure = StructType(original_schema)

df = self.spark_session.read.\
    csv(path=PATH_FILES+'\\*.txt', header=False, schema=data_structure, sep='\t').\
    withColumn("Filename", reverse(split(input_file_name(), "/")).getItem(0) ).\
    withColumn("duration", col("End") - col("Start"))

df.show(20, False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file using `spark.read.csv()` and If your columns delimited by `space` use  **`.option("delimiter"," ")`**.

- use **`input_file_name`** function to get the filename.

**Example:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark.read.option("header",true).\
option("delimiter"," ").\
csv("<path>").\
withColumn("file_name",input_file_name).\
withColumn("duration",col("end_time") - col("start_time")).show()
```

---

In case if rows are delimited by `space` then read the data with some delimiter that doesn't exist in the file.

- Then split the data with `\\s+` and explode now we will get the data into rows of dataframe.
- Using **substring** function extract `start_time,end_time` and substract them to get duration.

---

```
spark.read.csv("<file_path>").\
withColumn("input",explode(split(col("_c0"),"\\s+"))).\
withColumn("filename",input_file_name()).\
drop("_c0").\
show()
```

---

**`UPDATE`**

`Using array index:`

```
spark.read.csv("<file_path>").\
withColumn("input",explode(split(col("_c0"),"\\s+"))).\
withColumn("filename",reverse(split(input_file_name(),'/'))[0]).\
drop("_c0").\
show()
#or
spark.read.csv("<file_path>").\
withColumn("input",explode(split(col("_c0"),"\\s+"))).\
withColumn("filename",reverse(split(input_file_name(),'/')).getItem(0)).\
drop("_c0").\
show()
```

---

`From Spark-2.4+ Using element_at:`

```
spark.read.csv("<file_path>").\
withColumn("input",explode(split(col("_c0"),"\\s+"))).\
withColumn("filename",element_at(split(input_file_name(),'/'),-1)).\
drop("_c0").\
show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but to have only the file name and not the whole path, is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: @Karots96, I have **updated** the answer to extract only the `filename` using spark inbuilt functions..!

Answer (score 0):

Just another similar approach in Scala -
Reading the file using spark.read.csv() with delimiter as space and naming file names as
(assuming spark -> spark session has already been present)

```
val inputDF = spark.read
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("delimiter", " ")
      .csv("<path>")
    .toDF("start_time","end_time")

 val output = inputDF
     .withColumn("duration", col("end_time") - col("start_time"))
     .withColumn("input_file_name", input_file_name())
     .withColumn("file_name_splits", split(col("input_file_name"), "/"))
     // Getting the last element from the splits using size function
     .withColumn("file_name", col("file_name_splits").apply(size(col("file_name_splits")).minus(1)))
     .select("file_name", "start_time", "end_time", "duration")

// To show the sample data
output.show(false)
```